# Remove the windows border/Go fullscreen from a WPF Pages app

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF **Pages**(not Window) application, and I would like for it to go fullscreen without the border/seeing the windows taskbar. All the instructions i've seen are for WPF **Windows**.

Comment: I wonder if pages are "supposed to" provide such functionality, by definition i would consider them to be content which is dependent on its framing parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pages apps are designed to run inside a container. The container can be the browser or your own window.

It's up to the container to handle the full screen operation.

**edit** Ok, I get it. When no window is present, the framework creates one for you. You can access the window using `Application.MainWindow` and you can change the properties this way (vb code):

```
Private Sub Application_Activated(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
    Me.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized
    Me.MainWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None
End Sub
```

Nevertheless I don't recommend you to continue this way, create a Window and put a frame on it, so you can have more control on the window.

For more info on WPF Navigation check out this article http://www.paulstovell.com/wpf-navigation

Comment: Assuming my container is a WPF NavigationWindow(I guess my WPF Page is contained in it), how would I style it? (I guess that was the better question)

Comment: Exactly! You can style it using `WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None` and `WindowState=Maximized`. Beware that this will cover the taskbar. I use the WPF Shell Library for more granular control over the window style. http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell

Comment: Pardon me for noobyness but I'm not sure what my WPF Page is hosted in:the XAML for my Page only declares the Page. I am using NavigationServices to navigate between the Pages.

Comment: No worries, we are here to help :) When you run the project, is your page shown in the browser or in a custom window? (maybe a screenshot can help me understand)

Comment: It's not an XBAP, it runs in a window, complete with minimize/maximize/close buttons on the upper right hand quarter .

Comment: Then you have a Window in your project (maybe named MainWindow) and you can change the Style and the State

Comment: I can't seem to find this Window though...the first Page that is displayed when I run the program is a WPF Page.

Comment: Ok, I get it. When no window is present, the framework creates one for you. See the edited answer

Comment: Dude, you rock! I managed to convert your to C# though, and I had to add "Activated" event to my XAML. `<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             Activated="App_Activated">
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>`
and add the App_Activated event to the codebehind